# Regex pattern for the server log

Tags: java, regex

I have the following log message from the server and I am trying to identify regex pattern from the below message.

```
2015-10-01T03:14:49.000-07:00 lvn-d1-dev DevServer[9876]: INFO: [EVENT][SEQ=248717] 2015:10:01:03:14:49 101 sign-in_id=11111@psop.com ip_address=1.1.1.1  service_id=IP1234-NPB12345_00 result=RESULT_SUCCESconsole_id=0000000138e91b4e58236bf32besdafasdfasdfasdfsadf  account_id=11111  platform=pik
```

I have used the following regex pattern

```
.+\[SEQ=\w+\]\s*(\d+:[\d\d:]+)\s(\d+)\s*.+\=(.+)
```

Using the above regex pattern, I am able to isolate the date(2015:10:01:03:14:49) and Id (101) but I am unable to get the email (11111@psop.com) and service id separately.

In my regex pattern string; '\=' is pointing to the last '=' match. Am I missing something here? Kindly help me in identifying the regex pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of your regex is the problem: `.+\=(.+)`.

`+` matches as many characters as possible, only giving back as needed (greedy).

`.+` was matching *all* of the characters it could, up until the point `\=(.+)` could no longer be satisfied. That is why it was matching the last equals sign.

Instead of just searching for any equals sign, try this:

`.*\[SEQ=\d+\] (\d+:[\d:]+) (\d+) sign-in_id=(\S+) .* service_id=(\S+)`

The ids are matched by name, which works much better.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is by default greedy. That's why `.+\=` matched the entire remaining string until the last `=`.

Instead you can use the non-greedy version: `.+?\=` - note the `?`.

The complete version would look like this:

```
.+\[SEQ=\w+\]\s*(\d+:[\d\d:]+)\s(\d+)\s*(.+?)\=(.+)
```

In addition you shouldn't overcomplicate things. As already pointed out in [@InternetUnexplorers answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42405464/4668606): you should use the names associated with the required values as anchors to simplify matching. As long as none of the names are repeated something like

```
.+\[SEQ=\w+\]\s*(\d+:[\d\d:]+)\s(\d+)\s*sign-in_id\=(.+)
```

would work.